# PCA with ITK in Python

Tags: python, image-processing, pca, itk

Ineed to implement a PCA analysis with ITK in Python. After looking in the manuel, it seems easy enough.

```
typedef itk::ImagePCAShapeModelEstimator<ImageType,   ImageType >  my_Estimatortype;
```

However, in Python, I can't find the function. It should be something like

```
itk.ImagePCAShapeModelEstimator[ImageType, ImageType]
```

Am I missing something here, or is the ITK lib in Python not complete (I'm using the normal itk, not the SimpleITK)

Comment: is there any error when you are executing the command, if so please post the error message so that I can try to help

Comment: @Dinesh There is the following Error that the function is not available:        

AttributeError: 'LazyITKModule' object has no attribute 'ImagePCAShapeModelEstimator'

But this simply means that the lib can't find the function, no? I even downloaded the qtconsole for jupyter which supports autocompletion, and there simply is no such function.
I tried calling the function in C++, and it seems to be present (in C++)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ImagePCAShapeModelEstimator is not currently wrapped for ITK. If you look inside the ITK repository a ".wrap" file is needed for wrapping. This is currently missing for this class [1]. It is generally not too hard to add a wrap file by finding a similar class' wrap file and copying it.

[1] https://github.com/InsightSoftwareConsortium/ITK/tree/13ff271d953658d192805f6ddc3a15d5ae94a5bd/Modules/Filtering/ImageStatistics/wrapping

Comment: Is there any guide/ tutorial on doing this, or has this been done already? The .wrap files looks quite complex to me, but I'll have a look into that. Thanks for the answer.